# what Steps you follow and recommend to make windows xp work faster?

Tags: windows-xp, performance

after some months from running my windows xp i feel its getting old and slower.

i always hear about tools and applications that can make the windows faster, such as registry cleaners, but i am always afraid from those applications.

Which steps you did and trust which made your xp work faster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check what is being run at startup using [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), and get rid of anything you don't need. Also, use [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/)

Comment: I second the CCleaner suggestion.  It also provides a shortcut for seeing all programs that start up automatically, and it gives you an easier way to remove applications.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest not cleaning the Prefetch folder. See [this article](http://www.edbott.com/weblog/archives/000743.html) for reasons why this is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

- Defragment HDDs
- Uninstall all applications, which you didn't using.
- Clear applications at startup
- Set all services (Control Panel -> Administration Tools -> Services), which you didn't using to "Start Manualy"

Answer (score 1):

I right click My Computer, Properties, Advanced, Performance Settings, Adjust for best performance.
That turns off animations and similar (you can see exactly what it turns off, there are tick boxes).  It looks less pretty but makes a difference to performance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but anyhow, here are the measures I took to speed up the old xp laptop of my girlfriend (Asus A3F, Centrino Duo 1,6 Ghz, 1 GB RAM):

- [Convert the filesystem to NTFS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456984.aspx)
- Defrag the HD using [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/)
- Defrag the registry and all the other programmes using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER)
- Disable services (see [Black Viper's list](http://www.blackviper.com/category/guides/windows-xp/))
- Disable the themes (see wikiti's answers here)
- Replace the virus scanner with [Avast](http://www.avast.com)
- Deinstall Intel PROSet Wireless (if you have it, had a big impact on startup performance!)

Just my two cents ...

Philipp