# What is more effective for reviving performance - cleanup utilities or reinstalling the OS?

Tags: windows-7, installation, performance, ccleaner

My 1.5 year old Toshiba Net Book running Windows 7 is slowing down. Will running [clean-up utilities](https://superuser.com/questions/5672/what-steps-you-follow-and-recommend-to-make-windows-xp-work-faster) or re-installing Windows **be more effective** for reviving its performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reinstall will assure a "clean slate" while a utility can help only to a limited extent.

Utilities generally are somewhat limited in what they clean up to avoid breaking applications or worse.  They can be a good start, but a reinstall will usually be better

Comment: Just to confirm, clean slate means takes care of all memory de-fragmenting?

Comment: @Tommy, memory is implicitly defragmented every time you shut down or reboot...

Answer (score 4):

The only way to keep good performances with a PC is to perform maintenance on regular basis such as:

- Checking S.M.A.R.T. data of your HD and if the result is "good": then
  Running CHKDSK

  Suggested tools: Piriform Speccy or SpeedFan (there's an online s.m.a.r.t. tool)
- Suppress unused softwares and *UNutilities*
- Run Windows disk cleaner or BleachBit or Ccleaner (but avoid Registry "cleanup")
- Defragment the volumes of the HD :Suggested tools: Windows defrag or
  Piriform Defraggler or Auslogic Defragmenter or Ms TechNet
  Sysinternals contig
- Update Windows and applications: Suggested tool: Secunia Software inspector
- You may also check for PC temperatures and clean dust accumulated in
  the box...

Finally take a look at MS FixIt Center: Fix Windows system performance problems on slow Windows computers

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/slow_windows_performance/en-us

Hope this help. Let us know.  :)

Comment: Also keeping the startup clean, keeping an eye on CPU and memory usage and handle hoggers.

Comment: climenole, this is great info. I will need to start doign these things after I reinstall =) Why "avoid Registry cleanup"? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

"Registry cleaners" don't help appreciably, and can hurt by breaking needed connections. If you're going to re-install, it's a non-issue anyway.

I'll add that even a fresh install needs to be defragmented. When everything else is finished (win-updates, etc), run a good defrag program. I use MyDefrag.

Trim your startups. I like Autoruns from Sysinternals.